# Regex match exactly two colons

Tags: regex

I have these strings, I want to return regex confirm those patterns.

```
NS::varible.child // OK
variable.child // OK
NS:variable.child // NO MATCH
::variablename.child // OK
:variablename.child // NO MATCH
_variablename.child.x // OK
5variablename.child.x // NO MATCH
```

I want C++ variable name match without -> operator and template<>

I have come up with this regular expression.

```
[a-z\_:{2,2}A-Z][a-z\_A-Z0-9\.:{2,2}]*
```

`:{2,2}` doesn't seem to be doing what I want. It accepts a single colon too.

How do I check exactly two colons?  Even better a regex to match C++ variable constructs?

Comment: What is the problem with `::`? I mean why don't you use that in your regexp?

Comment: it also matches single :

Comment: Oh my dumb, misread your regexp. Back in a sec...

Comment: `[a-z_:{2,2}A-Z]` The quantifier loses its special meaning inside a character class, so this will literally match `{` or `}` or `,` or `2` (or the other chars, obviously).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the options:

```
/^((::)?[_a-zA-Z.]+)+$/
```

Play with it online on [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/DO2zJipQE8).

Comment: nice site :)
i made necessary improvement to accept what i want
^((::)?[_a-zA-Z][_a-z0-9A-Z.]+)+$

Answer (score 2):

```
^(\w+|::)(::|.)\w+.\w+
```

Give that a try. You can use "::" literally to match two ":"

Answer (score 1):

Like @Wiseguy said you can't use special characters inside a character class (the `[` `]`).  The correct solution is to use a grouping to alternate between your literal and the character class:

```
([a-zA-Z]|::)
```

**EDIT: More fully explained**

If you think about a character class it's just a specialized way of writing a group anyway:

```
(a|b|c|d|e|f|g)
```

is identical to:

```
[a-g]
```

so by using a group for extra characters you'll achieve the same thing.

Comment: Oops! I get it, it's inside `[` `]`  One sec. Will Edit.